# "supported external accessory protocols" and info.plist in xcode

Tags: plist, xcode4.3, external-accessory

I read through Apple's EADemo project. I then attempted my own. But when I made my own, there's no place to put the supported protocol string. In Apple's EADemo project, if you look at the project info or plist, there's a spot called "Supported External Accessory Protocols".

How can I get that field to appear in my project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind...I had to open the plist as source code and manually change it...

Comment: @Wolvorin: wrong, it does answer the question: it explains **exactly** how the OP solved the problem.

Comment: Sorry My bad, I totally got it wring :(

Answer (score 4):

The more common answer would be to select to "Add row" to your pList (just option click while on the page - no need to manually change source code) then scroll down or start typing in the name field "Supported External Accessory Protocols" then you can have that row added and it should automatically be set up as an array that you can then add your supported protocols to as items of the array